# Show backorder notice message in mini cart like checkout page

Tags: mini-cart, messages, magento2.4.4, backorder, notice

I want to show backorder notice message in mini cart how can I do that
just like that :
[image]

Comment: In mini cart which place would you like to show? explain in detail

Comment: just like checkout page after product detail in mini cart